# Can't see relations - Loopback 4 + MongoDB + openapi-to-graphql

Tags: mongodb, graphql, loopback

Beforehand, hello to everyone!

I initialize Graphql in Loopback 4 like this:

```
  const graphqlPath = '/graphql';
  // @ts-ignore
  const oas: Oas3 = await (<Oas3>app.restServer.getApiSpec());
  console.log(graphqlHTTP);
  const {schema} = await createGraphQLSchema(oas, {
    strict: false,
    viewer: true,
    baseUrl: url,
  });
  //@ts-ignore
  const handler: graphqlHTTP.Middleware = graphqlHTTP({
    schema,
    graphiql: true,
  });
  app.mountExpressRouter(graphqlPath, handler);
  console.log(`Graphql: ${url}${graphqlPath}`);
```

Then I have a relation Favors>User (a User can have many Favors, but a Favor has only one User). I've created this relation with `lb4 relation`, and **I haven't made any other change**.

User Model:

```
  @hasMany(() => Favor)
  favors: Favor[];
```

Favor Model:

```
  @belongsTo(() => User)
  userId: string;
```

At the moment of the query (`http://localhost:3000/graphql`) this is what happens:

```
{
  favors {
    id
    userId
    user {
      id
    }
  }
}
```

[image: Query result]

I have no idea if it has something to do with the `loopback-connector-mongodb` which does not match ObjectId correctly, but I have no clue how to solve this.

My package.json:

```
    "@loopback/core": "^2.12.0",
    "openapi-to-graphql": "^2.2.5",
    "loopback-connector-mongodb": "^5.4.0",
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Hello from the LoopBack team*

In order to allow openapi-to-graphql understand relations, the OpenAPI schema produced by a LoopBack application must describe [Links](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/3.0.3.md#linkObject) between entities.

LoopBack 4 does not provide such metadata out of the box. We have been discussing this use case in GitHub issue [loopback-next#2153](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/issues/2153), unfortunately we haven't found a clear solution yet.

What you can try: In your controllers, enhance your response specifications with a links section pointing to relevant API endpoints for accessing the related models.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I will try to do so and update this question with an approach.